# Binding component actions to route and getting the returned result

Tags: ember.js

Say I have the following component

```
{{my-component onSaved=(action 'save')}}
```

I want to define the "save" action on the route not the controller.

```
actions: {
  save(model): {
    return model.save();
  }
}
```

The returned promise is important as I need it in the component code.

```
const pendingPromise = this.attrs.onSave(model);
```

This does not work and says it can't find the action.  Is this possible somehow?  Even if I provide an action in the controller to simply call the one in the route there is still no way to get hold of the returned promise.

```
actions: {
  saveIntermediary(model) {
    this.send('save', model); // can't get hold of the response!!!!
  }
}

{{my-component onSave=(action 'saveIntermediary')}}
```

Comment: Is it possibly just a typo?: `onSave` vs `onSaved`

Comment: why don't you just call `model.save()` in your `saveIntermediary`?

Comment: @Remi from reading online and my own experience it is generally better to have actions that modify the model in the route as opposed to the controller.  This allows you to recycle the controller and template in other routes and simply redefining the actions api as needed.  The controller should be reserved for actions that modify the UI such as expanding an accordion or something like that.

Comment: @MartinSchneider yes a typo, will fix.

Comment: There's a property in your controller called `target` that links to its route, so you can do `this.get('target').send('save', model)`

Comment: A small suggestion: don't do `this.attrs.onSave(model)`, but instead do `this.get('onSave')(model)`.

Comment: @locks can you explain why?

Comment: @jax `this.attrs` shouldn't be used in classic components as it might not be what you expect. See the guides for usage and contact me on Slack for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route isn't connected to the template, that's why you can't normally bind a closure action from a route. There's two solutions at the moment:

- Move the action to the controller. The controller is the context of the rendered template, so they're connected.
- Use the [route action](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-route-action-helper) addon and keep the action in the route.